# Linq2DB Create dynamic table model

Tags: c#, linq2db

Is it possible to create a table model that depends on the user input ?
Globally I'll get a List containing the column names of the table that I should create in the DB.
The Question is how can I manage that as I don't know how many columns I must create.

The standard approach for a defined table (known structure) would be something like this:

```
[Table("TableName")]
public class TableName
{
   [PrimaryKey, Identity] public int Id;
   [Column] public string Name;
}

public void CreateTable(string configString)
{
   using (var db = new DataConnection(configString))
   {
      db.CreateTable<TableName>();
   }
}
```

Is it possible to create the table model dynamically, from something like this:

```
var userInput = new List<string>() { "Name", "Firstname", "Adresse", "Zipcode", "City" };
```

To get a model like this for the table creation:

```
[Table("TableName")]
public class TableName
{
   [PrimaryKey, Identity] public int Id;
   [Column] public string Name;
   [Column] public string Firstname;
   [Column] public string Adresse;
   [Column] public string Zipcode;
   [Column] public string City;
}
```

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Actually for now it is no way to do that without code change. DDL SQL generation is not a main purpose of the library. `CreateTable` was basically introduced for helping in creating temporary tables when classes are known. There possible way to generate classes dynamically, but I do not think that it worth time.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer. I'm a bit disappointed, but it's still a great ORM for the rest.

Comment: Actually this was requested earlier, but no time for implement. It needs new DDL API, like AddColumn, RenameColumn, DropColumn, ect.